# i want to replace java code using if-else to switch

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

i want java code using switch to same execute ? how i can do this by java

```
 if(ave>=90.0)
     return 'A';
 else if(ave>=80.0)
     return 'B';
 else if(ave>=70.0)
     return 'C';
 else if(ave>=60.0)
     return 'D';
 else 
     return 'F';
```

Comment: Fantastic. Write some code.

Comment: Capital D is 68 in ascii so you may do strVar=(Math.max(Math.min(68-(90-ave)/10,65)),68).toString(); but may not work for single chars maybe only strings

Comment: Is lack of `E` intentional?

Comment: @Pshemo It looks like the OP is writing some grade average to letter grade thing, so I'd say yes.

Comment: @DennisMeng Thanks, I needed to read a little about grading system in few counties to see that not everywhere between `D` and `F` `E` is used.

Answer (score 2):

The intuitive solution is: It's impossible.

A switch needs a discreet set of elements. A range of numbers is infinite and you can't do

```
switch(something) {
case 90.0:
case 90.000000000001:
....
```

There is a way you could do that though: Convert the range to some number:

```
private static int toRangeIndex(double d) {
    if (d >= 90.0)
        return 0;
    else if (d >= 80.0)
        return 1;
    else if (d >= 70.0)
        return 2;
    else if (d >= 60.0)
        return 3;
    else
        return 4;
}

public static double sumColoumn(double[][] m, int coloumnIndex) {
    switch (toRangeIndex(ave)) {
    case 0:
        return 'A';
    case 2:
        return 'B';
    case 3:
        return 'C';
    case 4:
        return 'D';
    default:
        return 'F';
    }
}
```

This is obviously not better in your case. But there are cases in which you could use such a technique.

Comment: It seems that OP is trying to avoid `if() else if()..`, not wrap it in separate method.

Comment: @Pshemo I know. And I wouldn't do that here because it's just more code. But if you have an object that keeps it's internal state as `double` it would be a good idea to add such a method so that code can use a simple `switch`. The conversion code exists only once, code that uses converted values can exist multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible directly, `switch` requires exact match.

What you can do is write function like:

```
int classify(double avg) {
    // perform some if-else chain, or loop with test inside, or calculation:
    return (int)(avg/10.0);
}
```

Then use the return value in switch:

```
switch (classify (avg)) {
case 10: // average of exact 100.0 gives 10, let's not F that...
case 9:
    return 'A';
case 8:
    return 'B';
//...
default:
    return 'F';
}
```

But, in your specific case it is just moving the if... ladder into a different function, and probably not good idea. So don't do it :-).

Or rather, if you do it, do it because it makes code easier to understand and maintain (and here it in *my opinion* does not), not because you want to use `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
int findIndex(double ave){
int index=(int)(ave/10.0);
if(index>=9)
    return 9;
else 
    return index;
```

}

```
switch (findIndex(ave)) {
    case 9:
        return 'A';
    case 8:
        return 'B';
    case 7:
        return 'C';
    case 6:
        return 'D';
    default:
        return 'F';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i finded answer

```
    switch(t1)
    {
    case 100: case 99: case 98: case 97:case 96:case 95:case 94:case 93:case 92:case 91:case 90:
    cr='A';
    break;
    case 89: case 88: case 87: case 86:case 85:case 84:case 83:case 82:case 81:case 80:
    cr='B';
    break;
    case 79: case 78: case 77: case 76:case 75:case 74:case 73:case 72:case 71:case 70:
    cr='C';
    break;
    case 69: case 68: case 67: case 66:case 65:case 64:case 63:case 62:case 61:case 60:
    cr='D';
    break;
    default:
    cr = 'F';
    break;    
    }
```